# How can I increase speed/performance with Scikit-learn regression and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am playing with the excellent Scikit-learn today.  I'm forming the x's out of panels sliced on the minor_axis and y's out of DataFrame sliced on columns.  At the moment I'm doing endless iterations, does any .apply() Masters out there have any idea how to speed this up ?

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
np.random.seed(247)
x = Panel(np.random.rand(3,25,10))
y = y = DataFrame(np.random.rand(25,5))
r2 = Series(index=y.columns)
for i in y.columns:
    X = x.ix[:,:,i]
    Y = y.ix[:,i]
    r2.ix[i] = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,Y).score(X,Y)

In [325]: r2
Out[325]: 
0    0.061945
1    0.091734
2    0.004635
3    0.015835
4    0.027906
dtype: float64
```

My idea was to apply this function (or similar) column wise. Have played with .apply() but because its a double(or triple) function call i.e. f1.().f2(x,y) or f1.().f2(x,y).f3(x,y) it gives me an error.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated and I think this would be a very useful bit of code to have out there!
LW

Comment: This looks about as optimal as it can get. If your `X` didn't change in the loop, then you could use the multitarget capabilities of the estimator to work with all `Y`s at once.

Comment: hi, my x's and y's do change , both have same column index

Answer (score 1):

You could do your calculations in parallel.  This isn't really making your code "better" but would definitely make things faster.  Something like ...

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

np.random.seed(247)
x = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(3, 25, 2000000))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25, 1000000))

def main(i):
    X = x.ix[:,:,i]
    Y = y.ix[:,i]
    r2 = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X, Y).score(X, Y)
    return r2

if __name__ = '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    p = Pool()
    result = p.map(main, range(1000000))
    print result[:2]  # print first 2 r2's

    end_time = time.time()
    print 'Iterations took %f seconds.' % (end_time - start_time)
```

**Output:**

```
[0.07197, 0.24436]
"Iterations took 159.226 seconds."
```

I ran a million regressions and as you can see it took ~2.5 minutes.  This will vary based on the number of cores you have.  `result` will be a list of your scores so you can easily reproduce the `r2` `Series` in your example.  Good Luck!

Comment: Looks interesting, will have a play. Does Pool() play nicely with Pandas Dates (timestamps) it you were to iter through those instead of numbers ?

Comment: You may consider doing this using `sklearn.externals.joblib.Parallel`, too.